# Add drop shadow to a lot of D3 force simulation nodes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 v4 force simulation with 100 nodes in it. Each node is an image and I would like to add a drop shadow to each image, however, I think because of the way I am rendering the drop shadow, this doesn't scale. With 100 images without drop shadow it runs 60fps but with drop shadow more like 8fps. Is there a hacky solution or maybe a better way to do this. Here is what I have right now (rendering on a circle behind the image):

```
var dropShadowFilter = this.d3Graph.append('svg:filter')
  .attr('id', 'drop-shadow')
  .attr('filterUnits', "userSpaceOnUse")
  .attr('width', '250%')
  .attr('height', '250%');
dropShadowFilter.append('svg:feGaussianBlur')
  .attr('in', 'SourceGraphic')
  .attr('stdDeviation', 2)
  .attr('result', 'blur-out');
dropShadowFilter.append('svg:feColorMatrix')
  .attr('in', 'blur-out')
  .attr('type', 'hueRotate')
  .attr('values', 180)
  .attr('result', 'color-out');
dropShadowFilter.append('svg:feOffset')
  .attr('in', 'color-out')
  .attr('dx', 3)
  .attr('dy', 3)
  .attr('result', 'the-shadow');
dropShadowFilter.append('svg:feBlend')
  .attr('in', 'SourceGraphic')
  .attr('in2', 'the-shadow')
  .attr('mode', 'normal');


this.node = this.d3Graph.selectAll(null)
   .data(Nodes)
   .enter()
   .append("g")
   .attr("class", "nodes");

this.node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 30)
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .style("filter", "url(#drop-shadow)")
```

Comment: if each node has an image appended to them, could you create a drop shadow effect in a photo editing application for each image, instead of using svg filters

Comment: This crossed my mind, however, unfortunately, I don't think so. The shadow would end up overlapping the other nodes when they get close to each other which wouldn't look right.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to do more of the heavy lifting yourself then you could consider approximating a drop shadow for simple shapes by adding nodes behind each item and scaling, positioning and colouring them appropriately.

In the example below I have created an additional circle which is slightly larger and offset from the top-layer circle. It also has a custom `fake-shadow` radial gradient applied.

```js
var d3Graph = d3.select('svg')

var dropShadowFilter = d3Graph.append('svg:filter')
  .attr('id', 'drop-shadow')
  .attr('filterUnits', "userSpaceOnUse")
  .attr('width', '250%')
  .attr('height', '250%');
dropShadowFilter.append('svg:feGaussianBlur')
  .attr('in', 'SourceGraphic')
  .attr('stdDeviation', 2)
  .attr('result', 'blur-out');
dropShadowFilter.append('svg:feColorMatrix')
  .attr('in', 'blur-out')
  .attr('type', 'hueRotate')
  .attr('values', 180)
  .attr('result', 'color-out');
dropShadowFilter.append('svg:feOffset')
  .attr('in', 'color-out')
  .attr('dx', 3)
  .attr('dy', 3)
  .attr('result', 'the-shadow');
dropShadowFilter.append('svg:feBlend')
  .attr('in', 'SourceGraphic')
  .attr('in2', 'the-shadow')
  .attr('mode', 'normal');

var simpleGradient = d3Graph.append('defs')
  .append('radialGradient')
  .attr('id', 'fake-shadow');
simpleGradient.append('stop')
  .attr('offset', "80%")
  .attr('stop-color', '#01AFAF');
simpleGradient.append('stop')
  .attr('offset', "100%")
  .attr('stop-color', "#01AFAF00");
```

```css
body {
  background: papayawhip
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg height="120" width="600" text-anchor="middle">
<text x="200" y="105">Original</text>
<text x="400" y="105">Fake Shadow</text>
<circle cx="200" cy="50" r="30" filter="url(#drop-shadow)" fill="red"/>
<circle cx="403" cy="53" r="32.5" fill="url(#fake-shadow)"/>
<circle cx="400" cy="50" r="30" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```